# How do I create a module that can be used like module.subsection.function()?

Tags: python

I'm working on a python module and i want to have it organised so that you only need to import the functions that you need for that project. How would i achieve this in the format `module.part.function()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your module [a package that contains sub-modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Use a file layout something like this:

```
toplevel/
    module/
        __init__.py
        part.py
```

The file `module/part.py` would contain the `function()` function you described. `module/__init__.py` would contain anything you want in `module` unconditionally (without importing any of the sub-modules).